# How does momentjs calculate months ago?

Tags: momentjs

I noticed something odd and I couldn't find any documentation on how momentjs calculate months ago.

Today is **Oct 2nd 2016**. When I call the following momentjs functions, I get

```
moment("20160617", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
"4 months ago"
moment("20160618", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
"3 months ago"
```

Can someone please explain to me why June 17th is 4 months ago and June 18th is 3 months ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess: it has to do with the range `moment` calculates for each string. Look at the key for **M** and it's 25 - 45 days. So "one month" can last up to about 15 more days than a usual month. Counting backwards, the 18th of a month is within that 15 day period from the 2nd of the next month. The 17th would be just out of that range. This is all assuming a month is "30 days", which it seems moment does for this kind of calculation.

Comment: This is right. https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/min/moment-with-locales.js#L3928

the actual factor is 30.436875 days in one month.